# Axios + Ionic React + Sails: _csrf token 403 Forbidden

Tags: ionic-framework, cookies, axios, sails.js, csrf

I am developing an API with Sails.js and an user App with Ionic-React. At page load I make an axios request to get the _csrf token. When I submit the data from a login form to sails I always get a 403 Forbidden response. I disabled csrf (config/security.js) in sails and then I could retrieve the response. I am sending the token in the header.

I am trying too to get the session cookie but its not working I think that might be why the server refuses the request.

Ionic App:

```
componentDidMount(this: this) {
axios.get('http://localhost:1337/api/v1/security/grant-csrf-token')
  .then(response => {
    const _csrf = response.data._csrf
    this.setState({
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        _csrf: _csrf,
      }})
  });
}
```

OnSubmit:

```
const { emailAddress, password, _csrf } = this.state.form;
const config= {
  data: {
    "emailAddress": emailAddress,
    "password": password,
  },
  headers: {
    "x-csrf-token": _csrf
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  jar:cookieJar,
};

axios.post('http://localhost:1337/api/v1/users/authenticate', null, config)
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
})};
```

On Chrome DevTools Network Response:

[image]

On Postman this same request works and I get a 200 with the user data, and the request does include the sails.sid cookie.

I do not want to disable csrf protection, that wouldn't be a solution. Is it the sails.sid cookie that I am missing?

Comment: From my experience using axios with sails. You need to send the csrf token as a header in the request. So in sails security.js file, set `allowCredentials` to true. Then in your axios post add `withCredentials : true`. Then add the csrf as a header. Something like `axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = _csrf` should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this,

```
axios({
                method: 'post',
                crossdomain: true,
                url: apiFormUrl,
                data: formData,
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                    "Authorization": access_token
                }
            })
                .then
```

and it works

Comment: I just tried it and it doesn't work for me sending the request in this manner

Comment: I sent the request as you wrote it, just changing "crossdomain" for "withCredentials". "crossdomain" parameter throws an exception on Ionic-TypeScript. On the header I tried "Authorization" as well as "x-csrf-token" as in Sailsjs docs. I still get a 403 - Forbidden response.